# Why spring cloud service uses mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have a Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment and we have configured Spring Cloud Service. In recent times we observed that we are having error and the cause of the errors lead us to mysql connection error. After flushing the connections we are back to access Spring Cloud Services (circuit-breakers and service-registry).

I would like to know why Spring Cloud Service needs MySQL. During Spring Cloud Service installation, we were asked to install mysql as well.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks,

Chandan

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Cloud Services is a Pivotal commercial product. You will have better luck using https://support.pivotal.io to ask questions about commercial products.

[Spring Cloud Services](http://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/index.html) implements a Cloud Foundry [service broker](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/) that manages the lifecycle of the service instances (service registry, config server, circuit breaker dashboard). The service broker needs to keep track of the service instances it has provisioned in a persistent data store, and uses MySQL to do this. The service instances themselves to not require MySQL.